# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of null of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, form-data

I am creating a little website that has chats on it. Currently, one can only send text messages and I wanted to open a file sender as well for sending image(s), video(s), gif(s).

I have encountered a few problems along the way, but so far got everything without the support of others. However, I am in great need of it now.

By using `FormData`, Ajax and jQuery, I am able to have real-time images sent from the client to the PHP server. The problem that I am facing is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of null

when trying to append a file to `formData`. Take a look:

```
function opencraze() {
    $(".browse_send_file").change(function () {
        var chat_id = "123";
        var formData = new FormData();

        formData.append("chat_id", chat_id);

        var name = document.getElementById('#browse_' + chat_id);
        var filemsg = name.files[0];
        formData.append("userfile", filemsg);
    });
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="chat_wcom" style="width: 25%;">
    <label for="browse_123" class="material-icons"></label>
    <input type="file" class="browse_send_file" id="browse_123" name="browse_send_file" style="display: none">
    <input maxlength="140" type="text" id="input_123" class="comin" placeholder="My message..." name="sendmsg" onkeypress="g(event,123)" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" style="width: auto;">
    <input class="hidden_index" type="text" value="123" name="chat_index">
</div>
```

What happens before everything is that when the user clicks on a `div`, this HTML above is generated and once it is generated, it calls the `opencraze()` function. Now, if one presses on the label of the chat, one selects the file and it activates the `.change()` jQuery function. The error is on the line of:

```
var filemsg = name.files[0];
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: `getElementById()` expects the 'id' as string without the jQuery selector `#`. So remove the `#` -> `document.getElementById('browse_'+chat_id);`

Comment: but since you already use jQuery you could also do it using that like so: `name=$('#browse_'+chat_id);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The native javascript [document.getElementById()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp) expects the 'id' as string without the jQuery selector `#`.
So remove the #:

```
var name = document.getElementById('browse_'+chat_id);
```

Or use the [jQuery selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) method:

```
var name=$('#browse_'+chat_id);
```